# add_rewrite_rule not working for blog category page

Tags: rewrite-rules

```
add_rewrite_rule('^blog/games/(a-z|z-a|most-recent|most-viewed)(/page/([0-9]{1,}))?\.html$', 'index.php?blog_category=game-guides&index_sort=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[3]', 'top');
```

after adding above rule I found 404 for below URL

http://localhost/blog/games/most-recent/page/2.html
and
http://localhost/blog/games/most-recent.html

also, I can find my rule in get_option( 'rewrite_rules' ).
games is blog category

Comment: Have you already flushed the rewrite rules? Just visit the permalink settings page (no need to click the "save" button).

Comment: Thanks, working after flushing rues from admin